# tensorflow no output (tf beginner level)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I'm having a problem with my tensorflow code, it won't output anything about the prediction and losses of my model. here's the code

```
const model = tf.sequential();



model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 4, inputShape: [3], activation: 'sigmoid' }));

model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 3, activation: 'sigmoid' }));



model.compile({

  optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.1),

  loss: "meanSquaredError",

});



const input = tf.tensor2d([

  [1,0],

  [0,0],

  [0,0],

]);

const target = tf.tensor2d([

  [5],

  [0],

  [0],

]);



train().then(() => {

  console.log("training complete");

  const prediction = model.predict(input);

  prediction.print();

});



async function train() {

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    const response = await model.fit(input, target, {

      epochs: 20,

      shuffle: true,

    });

    console.log(response.history.loss[0]);

  }

}
```

I've tried tweaking, put random values in the arrays (`inputs` `outputs`) but I never got my expected results! which is just some loss value and the goal data

can you please see what's wrong with my code?

thanks